# Sending an array of primitive types over a ClientRPC call

Tags: rpc, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am trying to send an array of various basic types over the Network using the `ClientRpc` attribute. The [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html) states, that I can send these over the Network without problems:

> - basic types (byte, int, float, string, UInt64, etc)
> - arrays of basic types

However, it seems holding them mixed together in an `object[]` array does not work. I have the following example:

```
[Command]
void CmdForwardEvent(string eventName, object[] args) {
    Debug.Log ("Broadcasting event: " + eventName);
    foreach (var o in args) {
        Debug.Log ("arg-class: " + o.GetType() + ": " + o);
    }
    RpcForwardEvent (eventName, args);
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcForwardEvent(string eventName, object[] args) {
    Debug.Log ("Received event " + eventName);
    foreach (var o in args) {
        Debug.Log ("arg-class: " + o.GetType() + ": " + o);
    }
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.P)) {
        CmdForwardEvent("Testevent", new object[]{"some string", 1, false});
    }
}
```

On the server, I get the output

```
Broadcasting event: Testevent
arg-class: System.String: some string
arg-class: System.Int32: 1
arg-class: System.Boolean: false
```

On the client, this arrives without any errors:

```
Received event: Testevent
arg-class: System.Object: System.Object
arg-class: System.Object: System.Object
arg-class: System.Object: System.Object
```

How can I send various amounts of arguments with different basic types over a ClientRpc call?

Comment: But it is working, isn't it? You can just unbox the values with casting to whatever primitive type you want on client. I don't really know what is the problem.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the Type on the Client side. Note that `GetType()` gives you the _actual type at runtime_, which got lost

Comment: Did you try `if(o is System.String)` and then cast it?

Comment: `o is System.String` returns false. The objects on the receiving end seem to be empty object, because their ToString yields `System.Object`. I updated the question to include each object's string representation

Comment: I see thanks, now I see the problem. I will try to find something.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround would be to manually serialize the array and send it as `byte[]`:

```cs
// new code

private BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

private byte[] objectToBytes(object os) {
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream ();
    bf.Serialize (stream, os);
    return stream.ToArray ();
}

private object bytesToObject(byte[] bytes) {
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream (bytes);
    return bf.Deserialize (stream);
}

// modified code:

[Command]
void CmdForwardEvent(string eventName, byte[] argsAsBytes) {
    object[] args = bytesToObject(argsAsBytes) as object[];  // deserialize
    Debug.Log ("Broadcasting event: " + eventName);
    foreach (var o in args) {
        Debug.Log ("arg-class: " + o.GetType() + ": " + o);
    }
    RpcForwardEvent (eventName, argsAsBytes);
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcForwardEvent(string eventName, byte[] argsAsBytes) {
    object[] args = bytesToObject(argsAsBytes) as object[];  // deserialize
    Debug.Log ("Received event " + eventName);
    foreach (var o in args) {
        Debug.Log ("arg-class: " + o.GetType() + ": " + o);
    }
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.P)) {
        // serialize
        byte[] bytes = objectToBytes(new object[]{"some string", 1, false});
        CmdForwardEvent("Testevent", bytes);
    }
}
```

output on client and server side are the same then, as expected.

Comment: I was think about it too. Thanks - can be usefull in the future.

Comment: Note that this approach is limiting, as you can't include some types Unity can otherwise natively send, like Networked GameObjects

Comment: Another drawback is that the `BinaryFormatter` from `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary` isn't available on a lot of .NET subsets. This can be fixed by using another, more widely available Serializer like the `XmlSerializer`